# How to call a function inside a controller in a directive on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive designed to call a modal dialog on button click:

```
.directive('myModal', function () {                         
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { show : '='},
            replace:true,                                                   
            transclude: true,                                               
            controller: function($scope, $filter,spService, spHelper, itemContainer) {
                $scope.toggleModal = function() {
                    $scope.convertArray();

                    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
                    $scope.currentQuestionIndex = 0;                                // initialize question index
                    $scope.answerCollection = [];                                   // initialize collection
                    $scope.answerCollection .value = null;
                    $scope.choicesSelected = "";                                    //  initialize for validation

                    $scope.currentQuestionObject = $scope.wizardQuestionSet[0];             //  start from question #1
                };

            // lots more functions here...
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.dialogStyle = {};

                if (attrs.width) {
                    scope.dialogStyle.width = "640px";
                }

                if (attrs.height) {
                    scope.dialogStyle.height = "660px";
                } 

                scope.hideModal = function () { 
                    scope.show = false;
                };

            },
            template:'<div class=\"ng-modal\" ng-show=\'show\'>' + 
                           '<div class=\"ngdialog-overlay\" ng-click=\'hideModal()\'></div>' +
                          '<div class=\"ng-modal-dialog\" ng-style=\'dialogStyle\'>' + 
                             '<div class=\"ng-modal-close\" ng-click=\'hideModal()\'>X</div>' +
                             '<div class=\"ng-modal-dialog-content\" ng-transclude></div>' + 
                        '</div>' + 
                     '</div>' 
        };
```

And in my HTML, I have the following button designed to call toggleModal() on ng-click:

```
<div class="expandStory" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">
    <span ng-click="$scope.toggleModal()" class="carousel-btns">
          Call my Modal
   </span>
</div>
```

I've tried calling toggleModal() using this approach to no avail. Am I missing something here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you as always for the tips. :)

**EDIT:** @developer033, I'm calling the directive in my HTML like this:

```
<my-modal show="carousel.modalShown" width="750px" height="auto">
    <!-- do something -->
</my-modal>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `directive`?

Comment: Hi, please see my edited question. :)

Comment: you are calling toggleModal() from outside directive ?

Comment: Yep. `toggleModal()` is not inside the `<trans-wizard-modal>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ng-click`, don't use `$scope`

instead of `ng-click="$scope.toggleModal()` Try this `ng-click="toggleModal()`

this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nkoLjdq/) shows `ng-click`, `onclick`, and `click event listener` methods

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Does this also apply when I call the directive in my HTML, for example `<trans-wizard-modal show='modalShown'>` instead of `<trans-wizard-modal show='$scope.modalShown'>` ?

Comment: @DeeJ. yeah. `<trans-wizard-modal show='modalShown'>` works as you expected

Comment: Did as you advised. It finally works again. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use $scope inside ng-click.Call it like this

```
<div class="expandStory" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">
    <span ng-click="toggleModal()" class="carousel-btns">
          Call my Modal
   </span>
</div>
```